# Restore application when receiving broadcast

Tags: android

I have an application A that has a broadcast receiver. 
This receiver listens to certain broadcasts I get from another application B.

Now when I receive a certain broadcast from application B I want to open my application A.
At the moment I have the following code in my broadcast receiver in application A:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if(intent.getAction().equals("startApplication"))
        {
            Intent LaunchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("packageName application A");
            context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
        }
    }
```

But this code always starts the main activity of application A.
When my application is already open in the background I want to restore the application rather than starting from the main activity.

Like when you press home in an application and return to it with recent apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make you main activity as `singleInstance` in the `manifest` of the app at `activity` level